# Does the dill python module handle importing modules when sys.path differs?

Tags: python, dill, pathos

I'm evaluating dill and I want to know if this scenario is handled.  I have a case where I successfully import a module in a python process.  Can I use dill to serialize and then load that module in a different process that has a different sys.path which doesn't include that module?  Right now I get import failures but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Here's an example.  I run this script where the foo.py module's path is in my sys.path:

```
% cat dill_dump.py 
import dill
import foo
myFile = "./foo.pkl"
fh = open(myFile, 'wb')
dill.dump(foo, fh)
```

Now, I run this script where I do not have foo.py's directory in my PYTHONPATH:

```
% cat dill_load.py 
import dill
myFile = "./foo.pkl"
fh = open(myFile, 'rb')
foo = dill.load(fh)
print foo
```

It fails with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dill_load.py", line 4, in <module>
    foo = dill.load(fh)
  File "/home/b/lib/python/dill-0.2.4-py2.6.egg/dill/dill.py", line 199, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/rel/lang/python/2.6.4-8/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/rel/lang/python/2.6.4-8/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "/home/b/lib/python/dill-0.2.4-py2.6.egg/dill/dill.py", line 678, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
ImportError: No module named foo
```

So, if I need to have the same python path between the two processes, then what's the point of serializing a python module?  Or in other words, is there any advantage to loading foo via dill over just having an "import foo" call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting failure. Notice that if you do `dill.dumps(foo)` you will get the contents of the module `foo`… the part that fails is using python's built-in import hook (`__import__`) to do little more than to register the module into `sys.modules`.  It should be possible to work around that and modify `dill` so that the module could be imported if the module is not found in the PYTHONPATH.  However, I do think it's proper that the module have to be found in the PYTHONPATH… that is what is expected of a module… so I'm not sure if it's a good idea. But it might be...

As noted above, for a file `foo.py`, with contents: `hello = "hello world, I am foo"`

```
>>> import dill
>>> import foo
>>> dill.dumps(foo)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_import_module\nq\x00U\x03fooq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03}q\x04(U\x08__name__q\x05h\x01U\x08__file__q\x06U\x06foo.pyq\x07U\x05helloq\x08U\x15hello world, I am fooq\tU\x07__doc__q\nNU\x0b__package__q\x0bNub.'
```

You can see the contents of the file are preserved in the pickle.

The primarily reason to use `dill` with modules, is that `dill` can record dynamic modifications to modules.  For example, adding a function or other object:

```
>>> import foo 
>>> import dill
>>> foo.a = 100
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'w') as f:
...   dill.dump(foo, f)
... 
>>>
```

Then restarting… (with `foo` in the PYTHONPATH)

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 25 2015, 13:16:30) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'r') as f:
...   foo = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> foo.hello
'hello world, I am foo'
>>> foo.a
100
>>>
```

I've added this as a bug report / feature request: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/123

Comment: One suggestion on how to implement this is to capture sys.path in the serialized data stream so that you know where the _foo_ module came frame when loading.  This would be useful in that it would allow greater portability of the python state where you could load up a python session on machines or shells with different settings.

Comment: @BrentV: Good idea.  That information should actually be in the `__file__` attribute.  So `foo.__file__` will tell you where it was loaded from exactly.  This could only be used when on the same computer, of course, so it's not a fully portable solution.  I was going along the lines of capturing the entire module code with `inspect` or `dill.source.getsource`.