# Is there a way to serialize a class such that it can be unserialized independent of its original script?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Or, is there a way to serialize and save a class from a script, that can still be loaded if the script is deleted?

Consider three Python scripts that are in the same directory:

##### test.py

```py
import pickle
import test_class_pickle

tc = test_class_pickle.Test()
pickle.dump(tc, open("/home/user/testclass", "wb"))
```

##### test_class_pickle.py

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "Hello!"
        self.var2 = "Goodbye!"

    def print_vars(self):
        print(self.var1, self.var2)
```

##### test_class_unpickle.py

```py
import pickle

tc = pickle.load(open("/home/user/testclass", "rb"))
print(tc.var1, tc.var2)
```

When I run `test.py`, it imports the `Test` class from `test_class_pickle`, creates an instance of it, and saves it to a file using `pickle`. When I run `test_class_unpickle.py`, it loads the class back into memory as expected.

However, when I delete `test_class_pickle.py` and run `test_class_unpickle.py` again, it throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/programs/python/testing/test_class_unpickle.py", line 3, in <module>
    tc = pickle.load(open("/home/sam/testclass", "rb"))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_class_pickle'
```

Is there a way I can save class instances to a file without relying on the original script's continuous existence? It would be nice if I didn't have to use something like `json` (which would require me to get a list of all the attributes of the class, write them into a dictionary, etc.), because all the classes are also handling other classes, which are handling other classes, etc., and each class has several functions that handle the data.

Comment: You can't do it with `pickle` but there's a third-party module named `dill` that can (I think).

Comment: `dill` may help. https://pypi.org/project/dill/. But I'm not sure how useful it is to import a class instance into a system that doesn't have that class.

Comment: @tdelaney Unfortunately, I get a similar error when running the same test using `dill`: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_class_pickle'`.

Comment: @martineau Unfortunately, `dill` doesn't work (see the above comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get `dill` to do it. Dill only stores definitions of objects defined in `__main__`, but not those in separate modules. The following function redefines a separate module in `__main__` so they *will* be stored in the pickle file. Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758608/355230.

##### test.py

```
import dill
from pathlib import Path
import test_class_pickle


def mainify_module(module):
    import __main__  # This module.
    import importlib, inspect, sys

    code = inspect.getsource(module)
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(module.__name__, loader=None)
    module_obj = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    exec(code, __main__.__dict__)
    sys.modules[module.__name__] = module_obj  # Replace in cache.
    globals()[module.__name__] = module_obj  # Redefine.


pkl_filepath = Path('testclass.pkl')
pkl_filepath.unlink(missing_ok=True)  # Delete any existing file.

mainify_module(test_class_pickle)

tc = Test('I Am the Walrus!')
with open(pkl_filepath, 'wb') as file:
    dill.dump(tc, file)

print(f'dill pickle file {pkl_filepath.name!r} created')
```

##### test_class_pickle.py

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, baz):
        self.var1 = "Hello!"
        self.var2 = "Goodbye!"
        self.foobar = baz

    def print_vars(self):
        print(self.var1, self.var2, self.foobar)
```

##### test_class_unpickle.py

```
import dill

pkl_filepath = 'testclass.pkl'

with open(pkl_filepath, 'rb') as file:
    tc = dill.load(file)

tc.print_vars()  # -> Hello! Goodbye! I Am the Walrus!
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example, the class you want to serialize is self-contained, i.e. it doesn't reference global objects or other custom classes of the same package, a simpler workaround is to temporarily "orphan" the class:

```py
import dill
import test_class_pickle

def pickle_class_by_value(file, obj, **kwargs):
    cls = obj if isinstance(obj, type) else type(obj)
    cls_module = cls.__module__
    cls.__module__ = None  # dill will think this class is orphaned...
    dill.dump(file, obj, **kwargs)  # and serialize it by value
    cls.__module__ = cls_module

tc = test_class_pickle.Test()

with open("/home/user/testclass.pkl", "wb") as file:
    pickle_class_by_value(file, tc)
```